# Obtener una tercera lista mediante la comparación de otras dos

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista

Tengo una lista de referencia llamada **'index'** y tengo un listado llamado **'list_one'**.

```
index = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]

list_one = [[5, 1], [6, 2], [6, 13], [7, 3], [7, 14], [8, 4], [8, 15], [9, 5], [10, 6], [10, 16], 
            [11, 7], [11, 17], [12, 8], [12, 18], [13, 1], [14, 2], [15, 3], [16, 5], [17, 6], 
            [18, 7], [19, 9], [20, 10], [21, 11]]

final_list = []
for i in range(len(index)):
    for j in range(len(list_one)):
        
        if index[i] == list_one[j][0] or index[i] == list_one[j][1]:
            final_list.append([index[i], list_one[j][0], list_one[j][1]])
            
print(final_list)
```

Lo que estoy intentando hacer es comparar:
Si cada elemento de **'index'**, está dentro de una de las listas de **'list_one'**, entonces agrego a su pareja.

Lo que busco es comparar las dos listas y obtener una tercera lista **'final_list'**, la misma que me debría quedar así:

```
[[1,5,13], [2,6,14], [3,7,15], [4,8], [5,1,9,16], [6,2,13,10,17], [7,3,14,11,18], [8,4,15,12], [9,5,19], [10,6,16,20], [11,7,17,21], [12,8,18]]
```

He intentado mediante un bucle anidado pero no está resultando, se tiene la idea, pero ¿qué solución resultaría mejor en estos casos?

Agradezco mucho la ayuda o retroalimentación, saludos cordiales.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supongo que no requiere mucha explicación

```
index = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 400]

list_one = [[5, 1], [6, 2], [6, 13], [7, 3], [7, 14], [8, 4], [8, 15], [9, 5], [10, 6], [10, 16],
            [11, 7], [11, 17], [12, 8], [12, 18], [13, 1], [14, 2], [15, 3], [16, 5], [17, 6],
            [18, 7], [19, 9], [20, 10], [21, 11]]

final_list = []
for i in index:
    elemento = [i]
    for pareja in list_one:
        if i in pareja:
            [elemento.append(x) for x in pareja if x != i]
    if len(elemento) > 1:
        final_list.append(elemento)
print(final_list)
```

**Edit**

La respuesta original no consideraba el caso en que un elemento en `index` no figura en `list_one`.

Modifique `index` agregando el elemento 400 (para probar) y agregue un `if` para chequear que se encontrara al menos una pareja antes de actualizar `final_list`.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu excelente aporte, aprendí algo nuevo, saludos cordiales @Candid Moe.

Answer (score 1):

Utilizando los arrays, para saber de que lado es el elemento a agregar se necesitan agregar los `if` independientes y no con un `or` creamos un elemento al ingresar al primer ciclo `for` que sera el que controle el numero inicial a buscar.

```
index = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]

list_one = [[5, 1], [6, 2], [6, 13], [7, 3], [7, 14], [8, 4], [8, 15], [9, 5], [10, 6], [10, 16],
            [11, 7], [11, 17], [12, 8], [12, 18], [13, 1], [14, 2], [15, 3], [16, 5], [17, 6],
            [18, 7], [19, 9], [20, 10], [21, 11]]

final_list = []
for i in range(len(index)):
    final_list.append([index[i]])
    for j in range(len(list_one)):
        if index[i] == list_one[j][0]:
            final_list[i].append(list_one[j][1])

        if index[i] == list_one[j][1]:
            final_list[i].append(list_one[j][0])

print(final_list)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por el aporte, saludos cordiales @Paulo44.